# Is it possible to set the precision globally for an "f" string?

Tags: python, rounding, precision

The following Python 3.8 code:

```
a = [(1/3, 1/6), 1/9]
print(f"{a}")
```

prints:

```
[(0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666), 0.1111111111111111]
```

I would like to print only three decimal digits. I tried:

```
print(f"{a:.3f}")
```

but got an error, probably because `a` is not a float.

I can write a recursive function that goes through `a` and rounds each element of it, but it is cumbersome.

Is there a simpler way to set a global "float printing precision", so that the above function would print something like:

```
[(0.333, 0.167), 0.111]
```

Comment: It's absolutely because `a` is not a `float`. You are converting a tuple to string, so how the floats are displayed depends on how `tuple.__str__` handles its contents. That's probably via `float.__repr__`.

Comment: Did you mean `a = [(1/3, 1/6), 1/9]` here?

Comment: There is no way to globally change the way `float` objects are represented, other than by modifying `float.__repr__`, which is not possible in a reasonable way since `float` is a built-in type

Comment: @JonClements yes, fixed, thanks